# Video App Development

Tags: security, video, mobile, download

I'm looking to develop a video app that streams and downloads content, but I'm not sure about the security protocols with regards to protecting the downloaded content from being copied/transferred to another hard drive. Does anyone have any insights about as how to proceed? Thanks.

Comment: Google DRM, CENC, widevine, playready, etc

Comment: as written this question is too broad, primarily opinion-based and also probably off-topic here. Please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask